# Execution time in PHP

Tags: php, execution-time

I have a few foreach loops and at the end of every I use

```
set_time_limit(30)
```

which restarts the counter back to zero.

Now the script runs for longer time (I fetch 5000-10000 articles using an API and store them in DB), but after a while (when it processes already lots of data) I get the "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded".

Could it be because of lack of memory? How could I tackle this problem?

The script is fetching articles using an API, and a foreach loop is used basically like this

```
foreach($articles as $article)
{
//do stuff with single article using $article

set_time_limit(30);
}
```

and I do not expect it that it needs more than 30 seconds to fetch and process a single article, but apparently after the script is run for some time, it hits that limit. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to allow the script to do a 5-secs job longer than a maximum of 30 seconds by using set_time_limit(9000) or something like that, which will probably get the job done but I suppose this is not a good way to solve the issue?

Comment: `set_time_limit()` accounts for the entire PHP page, not just your loop. It should not be in a loop.

Comment: Are you sure the query is actually getting to results before your `set_time_limit(30)` applies? If the query takes longer than 30 seconds to get to the first results, your code won't add any time to the total execution.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, as at the end of foreach loops (but just before the set_time_limit(30) ) there is a mysql query which inserts data into the database, and I manually can refresh the table in database and see the data being inserted every few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just make

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

the first line of your script?

Comment: That's funny. I just spit on my screen.

Comment: But is this the way to go? Foreach loop obviously takes every time a little bit longer to complete than previous.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the 30 seconds default is fine.
What should I rather do with the foreach loop obviously taking more and more time with each iteration?

Comment: @PHPglue, according to the docs, it means no limit will be imposed. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's worth [linking the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and quoting the relevant bit: "The maximum execution time, in seconds. **If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.**"

Comment: I though you wanted to impose a time limit.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some crazy reason you feel that you must impose a time limit, consider the following:

```
set_time_limit(0);
$n = 0; $inc = 1;
foreach($article as $v){
  // do stuff with $v - Less characters is faster
  $n+=$inc;
}
set_time_limit($n);
```

Change `$inc` to suit your needs.

Comment: Solved, with `set_time_limit(0)` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PHP has a function set_time_limit which sets the time limit of execution.
It has one argument set in seconds.
If you use like this,
set_time_limit(0)
then it will set unlimited time of execution.

Write this code in top.
```

You can refer more from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

- Thanks